# Python - nonblocking write to subprocess.PIPE?

Tags: python, stdin, nonblocking

I' developing with python for a Raspberry Pi video application. I modified a c-program that plays full hd movies to take input from a FIFO.

Like so:

```
$ ./hello_video.bin test.h264 < .my_fifo
$ echo 3 > .my_fifo
```

I can send numbers to the FIFO and the hello_video.bin will trigger the corresponding video clip and loop it forever.

Next step should be to make the videos triggerable from remote. This is what i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import threading
import Queue
import subprocess
import sys
from time import sleep

host = ''       # empty port = all local ports
port = 5005     
buffer = 2      # small buffer sufficient

player = "/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/hello_video.bin"
clip = "/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264"

p = subprocess.Popen([player, clip], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

class readFromUDPSocket(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data,addr = socketUDP.recvfrom(buffer)
            try:
                p.stdin.write(data)
                p.stdin.flush() 

            except:
                pass   


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create socket (IPv4 protocol, datagram (UDP)) and bind to address
    socketUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    socketUDP.bind((host, port))

    # Instantiate & start threads
    myServer = readFromUDPSocket()
    myServer.daemon = True
    myServer.start()

while 1:
    pass

UDPSock.close()
```

Unfortunately the hello_video.bin doesn't react as supposed to. The commands do not trigger any other video.

I tried to use p.communicate(input=data) instead. This works, but just once. Then it blocks and i can't receive any other data from the socket.

I have no clue how to fix this — hope you can help me,
Thank you

Comment: have you tried to send a newline after the data: `p.stdin.write(b'\n')`? Unrelated: you don't need the separate thread here.

Comment: I think you're missing an `EOF`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file